# tkinter frame has no geometry python tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

why do i  get this error?
this is my first time trying to understand what is going in a class but i cant seem to figure it out.
the app variable saves it as tkinter windowframe and that way i can put widgets on it but if i need to change the geometry how would i do this?. im sorry for my bad explaining.
Any help would do.

```
import tkinter as tk


class App(tk.Frame):
def __init__(self, parent):
    app = tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
    self.button = tk.Button(app, text="start")
    self.button.pack()
    app.geometry("500x400")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app1 = tk.Tk()
    App(app1)
    app1.mainloop()
```

Comment: `.geometry()` is a method of Tkinter windows (`Tk()` and `Toplevel()`).  It's meaningless on a frame.  You could apply it to `parent` instead of `app`, perhaps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you pass a parameter to class constructor, simply assign it to an instance property (by typing `self.instanceProperty = whatYouPassed`), then you can work on it.

```
import tkinter as tk


class App:
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.app = parent
        self.app.geometry("500x400")
        self.button = tk.Button(self.app, text="start")
        self.button.pack()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app1 = tk.Tk()
    App(app1)
    app1.mainloop()
```

Reading [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#a-first-look-at-classes) about classes might be useful.